# Resetting an alias

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

In my .bashrc file I created a new alias:

```
alias source=mvn eclipse:eclipse -DdownloadSource=true -DdownloadJavadoc=true
```

I executed `source .bashrc`, however I realized the horrible mistake I made and I have been trying to undo it since. I tried `unalias`, but that does not work. I tried a restart, but the alias still exists. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Delete the line from your `~/.bashrc`, after a restart (or logout) the alias should be gone.

If not, please post the output of `which source`.

Comment: The `which source` produces no output. I deleted the line and restarted the machine, however the alias still existed.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by renaming the ~/.bashrc to ~/.bashrc.orig. Then logging out and logging back in and then finally renaming ~/.bashrc.orig back to ~/.bashrc. Executing source ~/.bashrc loaded the aliases correctly, and restarting the machine shows it's been fixed.